# How do I fix those errors and get my code running?

Tags: python, function

This is a simple Tic - Tack - Toe game.

This is the code I tried (below).
It should have randomly printed a X or a O on a 4 x 3 grid.
Instead when I run it I get the following errors :

```
Line 38 : Redifining name 'grid_row1' from outer scope (line 3)
Line 38 : Redifining name 'grid_row2' from outer scope (line 3)
Line 38 : Redifining name 'grid_row3' from outer scope (line 3)
```

```
#importing modules and defining key variables
import random
grid_row1 = ["|", "|", "|", "|"]
grid_row2 = ["|", "|", "|", "|"]
grid_row3 = ["|", "|", "|", "|"]
 
#basic start

print ("Hello!\nLet's play Tic - Tack - Toe!")
user_char = input ("Would you like to use Xs or Os? (X / O)\n").upper ()

#setting user's and computer's symbol

while True :
    if user_char == "X" or user_char == "O" :
        break
    else :
        print ("Sorry, that is not a valid option. Please try again.")
        user_char = input ().upper ()
if user_char == "X" :
    comp_char = "O"
else :
    comp_char = "X"

#making first move

row = random.randint (1, 3)
place = random.randint (1, 4)
if row == 1 :
    grid_row1.insert (int (comp_char), str (place))
elif row == 2 :
    grid_row2.insert (int (comp_char), str (place))
else :
    grid_row3.insert (int (comp_char), str (place))

#defining print board

def print_board (grid_row1, grid_row2, grid_row3) :
    i = 0
    a = 0
    sym_count = 0
    pri1 = ""
    pri2 = ""
    pri3 = ""
    while i <= 4 :
        while sym_count <= 5 :
            if i == 1 :
                if grid_row1.index (a) == "|" :
                    sym_count += 1
                    pri1.join (grid_row1.index (a))
                    a += 1
                elif i == 2 :
                    if grid_row2.index (a) == "|" :
                        sym_count += 1
                        pri2.join (grid_row2.index (a))
                        a += 1
                else :
                    if grid_row3.index (a) == "|" :
                        sym_count += 1
                        pri3.join (grid_row3.index (a))
                        a += 1
        else :
            sym_count = 0
        i += 1
        a = 0
    print (pri1 + "\n" + pri2 + "\n" + pri3)

#printing board
    
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    print_board (grid_row1, grid_row2, grid_row3)
```

Comment: Don't give your function parameters the same name as global variables

Comment: Those aren't errors, they're linter warnings. In any case, that's unfortunately hardly the only bug in your program – for one, you're not assigning the result of `pri*.join` so it's not doing much.

Comment: You didn't even try to run your program, didn't you? It will run - until it hits an error if you input `X` or `O` because you try to convert this value to an integer.

Comment: as per @Matthias, the code breaks here `grid_row2.insert (int (comp_char), str (place))`  because the code tries to convert a string ('X' or 'O') to an integer...